# Static pdf not available

Tags: html, spring-mvc, hyperlink, vmware-server

I am providing an anchor in my Spring MVC application as follows:

```
<a href='<c:url value="/resources/um.pdf"/>' type='application/pdf' target='_blank'>Download User Manual</a>
```

But instead of serving the pdf file the server is returning **404** error , while it is serving the css, js and image files in the same directory perfectly from  the same anchor.

Comment: Are you sure the rendered HTML (i.e. what the browser is receiving) is actually a valid link to the PDF in question?

Comment: Yes! as I have verified it by changing the filename to another css or js one in the same anchor tag.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a dumb comment. What's the `<c:url value=.../>` for? Why not just put `href="/resources/um.pdf"`?

Comment: @Barney, href is context sensitive and <c:url/> counters that behaviour.